# bit演算子とジェネリックス

Tags: swift, swift3

整数型のビットの並びを表示するジェネリックス関数を作成したいと思っています。
最初に、UInt8型のみ対応を作成してみました。

ここで、1つの疑問があり、型に対するバイト数を知る方法がわかりません。
ネット拾ったコードでサイズを取得するようにしました。
sizeof()って使えますか？

```
func BitStringUInt8(n:UInt8)->String{

    var bitString : String = ""
    for i in (0...(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)*8-1).reversed() {
        if ((n >> UInt8(i)) & 0x1) == 0x1{
            bitString += "1"    
        }else{
            bitString += "0"
        }
    }
    return bitString
}
```

で、これを元にジェネリックスにしてみました。

```
func BitString<T>(n:T)->String{

    var bitString : String = ""
    for i in (0...(MemoryLayout<T>.size)*8-1).reversed() {
        print(i)
        if ((n >> T(i)) & 0x1) == 0x1{
            bitString += "1"    
        }else{
            bitString += "0"
        }
    }
    return bitString
}
```

if ((n >> T(i)) & 0x1) == 0x1{のT(i)でコンパイルエラーとなります。

型条件としてBitwiseOperationsとしてみたのですが、エラーが取れません。
教えてください。イニシャライズが無いとのエラーです。

また、なぜ、シフト演算子は「型」が同じにしなければならないのに、＆演算子は、
「型」を同じにする必要はないのでしょうか？

「0x1」はInt型となるはずなのに。。。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

先に疑問に思われている点から。

***sizeof()って使えますか？***

Swift2までは、`sizeof(UInt8)`と言う書き方が出来たのですが、Swift3では`sizeof`関数は削除されました。Swift3では、`MemoryLayout<T>.size`または`MemoryLayout<T>.stride`が`sizeof(T)`に相当すると思ってください。

***なぜ、シフト演算子は「型」が同じにしなければならないのに、＆演算子は、

「型」を同じにする必要はないのでしょうか？

「0x1」はInt型となるはずなのに。。。***

Swiftの`&`演算子もシフト演算子と同様に左項と右項が同じ型の場合にしか定義されていません。間違っているのは、 *「0x1」はInt型となるはず* のところですね。

Swiftのリテラル(定数表記)には特定の決まった型はなく、コンテキスト(文脈)によって、そのデータ型が決定されます。`0x1`が`Int`型となるのは、コンテキストにデータ型を決定できるような情報がない場合のデフォルトであって、常に`Int`型になるわけではありません。(これは他のC言語系文法を持った言語と大きく異なる点です。)

例えば、

```
let a: UInt8 = 3
let b = 0x1 << a
```

と言うコードは普通にコンパイルが通りますが、この場合`0x1`は`UInt8`型として解釈されるために *シフト演算子は「型」が同じにしなければならない* にも関わらずコンパイル出来るわけです。

---

さて、本題ですが、あなたのジェネリック版のコードを動かすためには、次のような条件が必要です。

1. `T(i)`と言うイニシャライザ構文で`Int`型の値`i`を`T`型に変換できること
2. 2つの`T`型の値(`n`と`T(i)`)で`>>`演算が実行できること
3. 整数リテラル`0x1`が`T`型として解釈できること
4. 2つの`T`型の値(`(n >> T(i))`と`0x1`)で`&`演算が実行できること
5. 2つの`T`型の値(`((n >> T(i)) & 0x1)`と`0x1`)で`==`演算が実行できること

残念ながら`BitwiseOperations`と言うプロトコルは4.の`&`演算が実行できるという条件しか現しませんので、あなたのコードはコンパイルできないと言うことになります。

上記5つの条件をすべて満たすようなプロトコルはSwiftの標準ライブラリには存在しないので、自分で宣言してやる必要があるでしょう。

```
protocol BinaryInteger: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral/*3.*/, BitwiseOperations/*4.*/, Equatable/*5.*/ {
    init(_ value: Int) //1.
    static func >> (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self //2.
}
extension Int: BinaryInteger {}
extension UInt: BinaryInteger {}
extension Int8: BinaryInteger {}
extension UInt8: BinaryInteger {}
extension Int16: BinaryInteger {}
extension UInt16: BinaryInteger {}
extension Int32: BinaryInteger {}
extension UInt32: BinaryInteger {}
extension Int64: BinaryInteger {}
extension UInt64: BinaryInteger {}

func bitString<T: BinaryInteger>(_ n: T) -> String {
    var result : String = ""
    for i in (0..<(MemoryLayout<T>.size)*8).reversed() {
        //print(i)
        if ((n >> T(i)) & 0x1) == 0x1{
            result += "1"
        }else{
            result += "0"
        }
    }
    return result
}


print(bitString(0x123 as UInt16)) //->0000000100100011
print(bitString(-0x12 as Int8)) //->11101110
```

(ちなみに`as データ型`と言うのが定数リテラルのデータ型を明示する場合のSwift流の記法です。)

Comment: 「Tをジェネリックな型パラメータとして宣言すること」についてですが、<T>は元々の質問ソースに含まれているものの、HTMLタグとの謎の兼ね合いで消滅していたようです。Markdownとして書きなおしたものを編集リクエストしましたのでその内解決するかと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、ありがとうございます。今までも同じような質問を何度か見たことがあるのに失念しておりました。回答の方、修正させていただきます。

Comment: 詳細な説明で、一旦理解ができたと思ったのですが、すっきりしない部分があります。＆演算子、==演算子が使用できるのは、T型は、BitwiseOperationsプロトコル、Equatableプロトコルを適合している記述しているからと理解はできましたが、＞＞演算子についても、あるプロトコルを適合することで、「static func >> (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self //2.」の記述が必要なくなるのではと思った次第です。シフト演算子に関してのプロトコルは無いのでしょうか？また、演算子とプロトコルの関係を調べるにはどうのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？。Appleの「Swift Standard Library」から検索などしてみたのですが、例えば、＝＝演算子とEquatableプロトコルの関係などリファレンスからわかるものなのでしょうか。

Comment: @TAKA さん、`>>`演算子を宣言したプロトコルが存在しないか調べてはみたのですが、見つけることができなかったので回答のような記述になっています。残念ながら現在のSwiftのサポート機能やAppleの公式ドキュメントからはある演算子を指定してそれを指定したプロトコルがあるかどうかは調べられません。(私も片っ端からGenerated headerのファイルを開いては、単なる文字列検索で調べていくというやり方でした…。当然漏れがあるかもしれません。)そのようなドキュメントの検索機能がつくかどうかは怪しいですが、現在Standard Libraryにあるようなプロトコルだけでは整数型に関するgenericなメソッド・関数が書きにくい(書けない)と言う状態であるという認識はSwift開発チームにあるようなので、Swift4までには何らかのプロトコルが追加されるかもしれません。([SE-0104](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md)で提案されているプロトコルもまだ全部は実装されていませんし。)時間的なことを言えば、既存のプロトコルがあるかどうか調べている暇に自前のプロトコルに後3行書き加えた方が早かったでしょう…。